# changing the sorted column value change the sorting list , while wants to use the ThenByDescending on first ordered list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have following code, In which there are list of students , and I want to sort the students first by value column which contains decimal values and after that I want to sort the already sorted list with same column but with different values . Just for understanding , I changed values using foreach loop in the below example.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var students = new List<Student>()
                {
                    new Student() { StudentId=1,Name = "Alice", Appd = 10, Value = 3.5 },
                    new Student() { StudentId=2,Name = "Bob", Appd = 10, Value = 3.7 },
                    new Student() { StudentId=3,Name = "Raul", Appd = 10, Value = 0.1 },
                    new Student() { StudentId=4,Name = "Charlie", Appd = 0, Value = 3.6 },
                    new Student() { StudentId=5,Name = "Dave", Appd = 0, Value = 3.9 },
                    new Student() { StudentId=6,Name = "Emma", Appd = 0, Value = 3.8 }
                };
            var orderedFields = students.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);//5,6,2,4,1,3
            foreach (  Student s in orderedFields )
            {
                s.Value = 120; 
            }
            orderedFields = orderedFields.ThenByDescending(x => x.Value);
            var newlist1 = orderedFields.Select(X => X.StudentId).ToList(); 
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Appd { get; set; }

        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but as soon I change the Value column values it start to change the order of items in list , and if I take this in another list then I will be not able to use the `ThenByDescending` feature results.

This is sample code to simplify the problem , in real example these columns name come from Database and based on those columns I want to sort the list, first by first column and then by another columns mentioned. For example in MySQL it will be something like this `order by col1 desc, col2 desc.`

As everybody is comments is discussing the clone and then sort again the list . so here is issue with that approach.

#1. First Set sorting values in Value column for each student :
Value column first contains for each student either 1 or 0 depending on its enrollment date from the cut off date.

#2 Then on same Value column there is CGPA for each student so student should be sorted based on that.

> In short all students who apply before cut off date should appear
> first and then sort by descending CGPA and then students who apply
> after cut off date but those also should come in descending order of
> CGPA.

**problem is I have only one column here for values, on which need to be sort.**

Second edit :

```
 if (_trackConfigManager.RankDependentOnFields.Any())
                {
                    infoFields.ForEach(x => x.PropertyToCompare = _trackConfigManager.RankDependentOnFields.FirstOrDefault().FieldId);
    
                    //Order the table withrespect to the firstfield
                    var orderedFields = infoFields.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);
    
                    //Then skip the first element and order the rest of the fields by descending.
                    foreach (var field in __trackConfigManager.RankDependentOnFields.RemoveFirst())
                    {
                        infoFields.ForEach(x => x.PropertyToCompare = field.FieldId);
                        orderedFields = orderedFields.ThenByDescending(x => x.Value);
                    }
    
                    //Format a studentId, Rank dictionary from the above orderded table
                    int rank = 1 + GetMaxRank(programId, statusId);
    
    }
```

and RankAggregate class as follow :

```
public class RankAggregate
    {
        public student_highschool_info HsInfoObj { get; set; }
        public student_interview_info IntInfoObj { get; set; }
        public student StuObj { get; set; }
        private student_program SpObj { get; set; }
        public string PropertyToCompare { get; set; }
        public bool IsDateTimeField { get; set; }
        public long StudentId { get; set; }
        public int Choice { get; set; }

        public double Value
        {
            get
            {
                var tokens = PropertyToCompare.Split(new char[] {':'});
                if (tokens.Count() > 1)
                {
                    PropertyToCompare = (Choice == 1)
                        ? "student_interview_FirstPrgTotalScore"
                        : (Choice == 2) ? "student_interview_SecondPrgTotalScore" : "dummy";
                }
                
                    var fldInfo = ReflectionUtility.GetPublicPropertyName(typeof(student_highschool_info), PropertyToCompare);

                    if (fldInfo != null)
                    {
                        if (HsInfoObj == null)
                            return 0;

                        IsDateTimeField = (fldInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?));

                        if (IsDateTimeField)
                        {
                            var val1 = ReflectionUtility.GetValueOfPublicProperty(typeof(student_highschool_info),
                                PropertyToCompare, HsInfoObj) ?? 0;

                            var dt = DateTime.Parse(val1.ToString());

                            return -Convert.ToDouble(dt.Ticks);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var val1 = ReflectionUtility.GetValueOfPublicProperty(typeof(student_highschool_info),
                                PropertyToCompare, HsInfoObj) ?? 0;

                            return Convert.ToDouble(val1);
                        }


                    }

                    fldInfo = ReflectionUtility.GetPublicPropertyName(typeof(student_interview_info), PropertyToCompare);

                    if (fldInfo != null)
                    {
                        if (IntInfoObj == null)
                            return 0;

                        IsDateTimeField = (fldInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?));

                        if (IsDateTimeField)
                        {
                            var val1 = ReflectionUtility.GetValueOfPublicProperty(typeof(student_interview_info),
                                PropertyToCompare, IntInfoObj) ?? 0;

                            var dt = DateTime.Parse(val1.ToString());

                            return -Convert.ToDouble(dt.Ticks);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var val1 = ReflectionUtility.GetValueOfPublicProperty(typeof(student_interview_info),
                                PropertyToCompare, this.IntInfoObj) ?? 0;

                            return Convert.ToDouble(val1);
                        }

                    }

                    fldInfo = ReflectionUtility.GetPublicPropertyName(typeof(student), PropertyToCompare);

                    if (fldInfo != null)
                    {
                        if (StuObj == null)
                            return 0;

                        IsDateTimeField = (fldInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?));

                        if (IsDateTimeField)
                        {
                            var val1 = ReflectionUtility.GetValueOfPublicProperty(typeof(student),
                                PropertyToCompare, StuObj) ?? 0;

                            var dt = DateTime.Parse(val1.ToString());

                            return -Convert.ToDouble(dt.Ticks);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var val1 = ReflectionUtility.GetValueOfPublicProperty(typeof(student),
                                PropertyToCompare, this.StuObj) ?? 0;

                            return Convert.ToDouble(val1);
                        }
                    }

                    return 0.0;
            }    
        }

        public RankAggregate(long studentId, student_highschool_info _hsInfo, student_interview_info _intInfo, student _profileInfo, student_program _spInfo)
        {
            StudentId = studentId;
            HsInfoObj = _hsInfo;
            IntInfoObj = _intInfo;
            StuObj = _profileInfo;
            SpObj = _spInfo;

            if (SpObj != null)
            {
                Choice = SpObj.choice;
            }
        }

       
    }
```

Comment: What's the *actual* problem? What you describe is the same behavior you'd find in a database. If you change the values in a way that changes the order and execute the order again, you'll get different results

Comment: If you want *ascending* sort, use `OrderBy`, not `OrderByDescending`

Comment: I want to preserve the first order and then wants to apply sort on second time but with different values in same column.

Comment: Then make a clone of the list.

Comment: Why not preserve the first value  and do the sort at the end

Comment: In cloning , sorting will be completely on the new column values , I want sort first by first set of values then on same list sort by second set of values.  For example first set containst 10,10,0,0  values for each student respectivaley and  second set contains 1,4,3.5,0.5 , so I want result should be first it appear all 10 results set and then sort that set by second values set . then 0 set and those internally sort by second values set.

Comment: `IEnumerable<>` is essentially a query, not a data container. `OrderBy` returns a query, not a set of results. Every time you enumerate it it executes from the start. That's equivalent to executing a `SELECT` query multiple times. `orderedFields.ThenByDescending` is identical to writing ` students.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ThenByDescending(x => x.Value)` which in turn is no different than just `students.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)`

Comment: yes, that's issue exactly as changing the column change the values and then reapplying the same sorting doesn't make any difference. what solution I can apply here ? I want to sort by two different values set for one column. In real application I am using reflection to get the values for the fields and then apply resort but as compartoProperty change its changes the values and resort and applying sort again doesn't make any difference.

Comment: `here is issue with that approach.` there's no problem with that approach. It's the only one if you want two different ordered lists. On the contrary `I have only one column here for values` that's a huge problem. `Value` should never be two completely unrelated things like that. That's a logic and design bug, plain and simple. If you want to short by enrollment date and CPA, use two different properties, one for the enrollment date and one for the CPA. If you want a cutoff indicator, add a property for that. A computed property may be good enough

Comment: `I want to sort by two different values set for one column` is the exact opposite of `I have only one column here for values`. Why is `Value` used to hold unrelated data in the first place?

Comment: If you have an `EnrollmentDate` property you can calculate the `AfterCutoff` property either as a computed property `AfterCutoff => EnrolmentDate > this.Course.CutoffDate;` or as an extension method that can accept an arbitrary cutoff parameter, `public static bool IsAfterCutoff(this DateTime enrollment, DateTime cutoff)=>enrollment>cutoff;` Both can be used in LINQ-to-Object queries

Comment: In MySQL though, you'll have to either calculate a flag for every row (veeeeerrrrry slow) or create a UNION ALL of two queries returning results before and after the cutoff. If you want to take the first 50 applicants for example, the UNION ALL queries allow you to quickly find and match the necessary rows while an `IF()` would have to scan all table rows just to calculate the `AfterCutoff`

Comment: It looks like the entire problem is caused by trying to use `RankAggregate` to calculate stuff that should be calculated by the database itself. That `1 + GetMaxRank` sounds like an attempt to calculate `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()`. Once again, explain the *actual* problem - you want to rank student applications by X, Y, Z criteria. That's relatively easy to do in MySQL using ranking functions. If you can't generate that SQL using your ORM, don't use the ORM. ORMs aren't meant for reporting queries, and LINQ isn't embedded SQL

Comment: you want to rank student applications by X, Y, Z criteria.  : Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why can't you add another field to the Student class, anyway since you can't do that, you have to fix these values in some places, for example using a tuple:

```
var studentsWithValues = students.Select(s => (s, s.Value))
                                 .ToList();
```

Then after changing the values, you can sort the above array:

```
var orderedFields = studentsWithValues.OrderByDescending(t => t.Value)
                                      .ThenByDescending(t => t.s.Value)
                                      .Select(t => t.s)
```

---

**Update for uncertain columns**

Bind each student object with a list of values:

```
var studentsWithValues = students.Select(s => new
{
    Student = s,
    Values = new List<double> { s.Value }
})
.ToList();
```

After the values are updated, append each value to the binded list:

```
UpdateValues();
studentsWithValues.ForEach(t => t.Values.Add(t.Student.Value));
```

Then you can sort these values:

```
var e = studentsWithValues.OrderByDescending(t => t.Values[0]);
var valueCount = studentsWithValues.First().Values.Count;
for (int i = 1; i < valueCount; i++)
{
    int j = i;
    e = e.ThenByDescending(t => t.Values[j]);
}
var orderedFields = e.Select(t => t.Student);
```

Comment: because those fields are selected by user and come to program from Database.  second you are on track from solution perspective but its for when there is only two values , what if there are 10 columns on which User wants sorting .  Likes sort by first column and then on same sorted apply sorting on second column values and then third column values etc.

Comment: @rahularyansharma you didn't mention that in the question. You can't use the same field for different values. There's no if or but in this. shingo's answer shows an alternate, one that could even work with an arbitrary number of fields, by wrapping one tuple in another. It would be a **lot** better if you described the actual problem though, because there are definitely better answers. Especially if you actually want a SQL query. LINQ isn't SQL

Comment: `what if there are 10 columns on which User wants sorting` that's actually very easy with LINQ, if you have proper properties. You can append `.ThenBy..` dynamically, eg `if (orderByX){ query=query.ThenBy(s=>s.X);}`. Are you trying to construct a LINQ expression for a reporting grid? There are similar questions already. It's not trivial, but you could use a library like LinqKIT to construct a dynamic EF query from user options

Comment: No matter how many columns you will have, you have to save these values before sorting. The easiest way is changing `double` to `List<double>` then you can sort as many as values. To extend from my code, check the update.

Comment: what is this UpdateValues(); method do ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma A pseudo method to explain the order of updates.

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

Use:

```
var orderedStudents = students
    .OrderByDescending(student => student.Value)
    .ToList();

foreach (Student student in orderedStudents) etc.
```

### Longer answer

Your `orderedFields` is not a list, nor a sequence. It is an object that can be enumerated. It has not been enumerated yet. In other words: it is not a `Collection<T>`, it is an `IEnumerable<T>`. Usually in descriptions you'll find the phrases: *delayed execution* or *deferred execution*.

When you execute `foreach (Student s in orderedFields)`, you start to enumerate the items in `students`. You don't enumerate the items in the original order, you enumerate them ordered by `.Value`.

> but as soon I change the Value column values it start to change the order of items in list

So, the next time you enumerate `orderedFields`, the items in `students` are enumerated again, and ordered again by the changed value of `.Value`.

If you want to change the source of the items in your LINQ statement, you have to execute the delayed execution by calling one of the LINQ methods that doesn't return  `IEnumerable<T>`, like `ToList(), ToArray(), ToDictionary()`, but also `FirstOrDefault(), Sum(), Count(), Any()`

By calling one of the non-delayed methods, the source is enumerated and the result is put in a new object. If you change the items in the new object, and use this new object as source for your next LINQ-statement, then the order of the new object is used, not the order in the original object.

Careful: if you put the references of the original items in the new List, and you change the values, you change the original items. If you don't want that, use a `Select(student => new {...})` to put the values in a new object. If you change those values, the original students are not affected.